# Python while loop not working like i want it to. Building rock,paper scissors game

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a huge problem with my game. Whenever I run the shell(cmd) only runs it once and its supposed to run 10 times. I've tried everything, in fact i just recently changed the while loop to a function but it didn't help. I tried refreshing m pc but that did'nt help either. Does somebody kow how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
import random

pc_rock = 1
pc_paper = 2
pc_scissors = 3

you_rock = ['1', 'rock', 'one']
you_paper = ['2', 'paper', 'two']
you_scissors = ['3', 'scrissors', 'three']

def ifs():
    turns = 0
    while turns < 10:
        turns = turns + 1
        pc_score = 0
        you_score = 0
        if you == you_rock and comp == pc_rock:
            print "Draw"
        elif you == you_rock and comp == pc_paper:
            print "You lose"
            pc_score = pc_score + 1
        elif you == you_rock and comp == pc_scissors:
            print "You win"
            you_score = you_score + 1
        elif you == you_paper and comp == pc_paper:
            print "Draw"
        elif you == you_paper and comp == pc_rock:
            print "You win"
            you_score = you_score + 1
        elif you == you_paper and comp == pc_scissors:
            print "You lose"
            pc_score = pc_score + 1
        elif you == you_scissors and comp == pc_scissors:
            print "Draw"
        elif you == you_scissors and comp == pc_rock:
            print "You lose"
            pc_score = pc_score + 1
        elif you == you_scissors and comp == pc_paper:
            print "You win"
            you_score = you_score + 1
    else:
        print  you_score , "is your score"
        print  pc_score , "is the pc's score"
        if you_score > pc_score:
            print "You win!"
        elif pc_score > you_score:
            print "You lose!"
        elif pc_score == you_score:
            print "Its a Draw!"


comp = random.randrange(1, 4)
print "You are about to play a fun game of rock, paper and scissors against"
print "your pc"
print "It is completely random so the pc can lose"
print "You will play 10 rounds"
print "Do you pick rock, paper or scissors"
print "ROCK = 1"
print "PAPER = 2"
print "SCISSORS = 3"
you = raw_input('>>>>')

#Pc ifs 
#__________________


if comp == pc_rock:
    print "The PC picks rock"
elif comp == pc_paper:
    print "The PC picks paper"
elif comp == pc_scissors:
    print "The PC picks scissors"
else:
    print " ERROR |" * 10
    print "STH WENT WRONG PLEASE GO BACK AND CHECK THE CODE"


#You ifs 
#__________________
if you in you_rock:
    print "You picked rock"
    ifs()
elif you in you_paper:
    print "You picked paper"
    ifs()
elif you in you_scissors:
    print "You picked scissors"
    ifs()
else:
    while you != you_rock or you_paper or you_scissors:
        print "Either rock paper or scissors please!"
        you = raw_input('>>>>')
        ifs()
```

Comment: Your while loop is in the wrong place. Identify the section of code that you wish to be repeated 10 times (this will no doubt include the section that contains the `raw_input()`) and wrap that inside the while loop. Your function should take two arguments, the computers choice (based on the random selection) and your choice.

Comment: Your code could be really easy to read and understand : http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-game-rock-paper-scissors/

Answer (score 0):

- You are comparing an integer value with a list `you == you_rock`,
  within the function.
- So it returns false, as there is no else within the while loop it
  doen,t print anything. But the loop executes 10 times.
- Replace `you == you_rock` as `you == you_rock[0]` as well as change
  other if conditions.

Now run the program, you will see that it executes 10 times.

> NOTE : Your while loop is wrongly placed. Change it according to your
>   required output.

Comment: thanks for the advice. By the way i'm using python 2.7, but i'll find out how to convert it. I think your code rewrite helped

Comment: Good to hear that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you have the `while` loop in the wrong place.  I've modified your code so that the game runs properly, 10 times (and added a few `print` statements to clarify what turn it is), but there are still some bugs you need to sort out.

```
import random

pc_rock = 1
pc_paper = 2
pc_scissors = 3

you_rock = ['1', 'rock', 'one']
you_paper = ['2', 'paper', 'two']
you_scissors = ['3', 'scrissors', 'three']

def game():
    print( "You are about to play a fun game of rock, paper and scissors against")
    print( "your pc")
    print( "It is completely random so the pc can lose")
    print( "You will play 10 rounds")
    turns = 0
    pc_score = 0
    you_score = 0
    while turns < 10:
        comp = random.randrange(1, 4)
        print( "Current round: " + str(turns + 1))
        print( "Your score: " + str(you_score))
        print( "PC score: " + str(pc_score))
        print( "Do you pick rock, paper or scissors")
        print( "ROCK = 1")
        print( "PAPER = 2")
        print( "SCISSORS = 3")
        you = raw_input('>>>>')

        #Pc ifs
        #__________________


        if comp == pc_rock:
            print( "The PC picks rock")
        elif comp == pc_paper:
            print( "The PC picks paper")
        elif comp == pc_scissors:
            print( "The PC picks scissors")
        else:
            print( " ERROR |" * 10)
            print( "STH WENT WRONG PLEASE GO BACK AND CHECK THE CODE")


        #You ifs
        #__________________
        if you in you_rock:
            print( "You picked rock")
        elif you in you_paper:
            print( "You picked paper")
        elif you in you_scissors:
            print( "You picked scissors")
        else:
            while you != you_rock or you_paper or you_scissors:
                print( "Either rock paper or scissors please!")
                you = raw_input('>>>>')
        turns = turns + 1

        if you == you_rock and comp == pc_rock:
            print( "Draw")
        elif you == you_rock and comp == pc_paper:
            print( "You lose")
            pc_score = pc_score + 1
        elif you == you_rock and comp == pc_scissors:
            print( "You win")
            you_score = you_score + 1
        elif you == you_paper and comp == pc_paper:
            print( "Draw")
        elif you == you_paper and comp == pc_rock:
            print( "You win")
            you_score = you_score + 1
        elif you == you_paper and comp == pc_scissors:
            print( "You lose")
            pc_score = pc_score + 1
        elif you == you_scissors and comp == pc_scissors:
            print( "Draw")
        elif you == you_scissors and comp == pc_rock:
            print( "You lose")
            pc_score = pc_score + 1
        elif you == you_scissors and comp == pc_paper:
            print( "You win")
            you_score = you_score + 1
        print('')
    else:
        print(  you_score , "is your score")
        print(  pc_score , "is the pc's score")
        if you_score > pc_score:
            print( "You win!")
        elif pc_score > you_score:
            print( "You lose!")
        elif pc_score == you_score:
            print( "Its a Draw!")

game()
```

You'll probably notice that the section of `if` and `elif` statements to determine who won each round, and to increment that player's score, does not function properly.  The scores remain at 0 after every turn.  I was thinking about just fixing it, but I think that will be a fun debugging exercise for you.  Happy coding!